# c++ rand() insignificant change

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I ran into an issue when trying to generate random numbers where it outputs an ascending sequence of numbers with increments of 3 every second. I am using mingw g++ 6.3.0 with the following compiler flags: -std=c++11 -Wall.

As an example, after running the following code and running the executable multiple times it provides the following output below:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  std::srand(std::time(0));

  int rnd = std::rand();
  std::cout << rnd << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
C:\...>make
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall    -o a.exe

C:\...>a
21154

C:\...>a
21157

C:\...>a
21157

C:\...>a
21157

C:\...>a
21160

C:\...>a
21160

C:\...>a
21163

C:\...>a
21163
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is not ideal](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Using `time(NULL)` as a random number will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to seed the random number generator at all? The default probably has far better entropy than a number that changes by 1 every second.

Comment: @Botje the default has no entropy at all

Comment: `std::rand()` isn't very random, especially immediately after seeding it with `std::time(0)`. This is expected behavior for the `rand()` function - if you don't like it (and you shouldn't), use a different RNG.

Comment: @Botje The default seed is always `1` when a program starts.

Comment: @harold TIL. I'm spoiled by high-level languages that do. I also found out that the `rand` man page for MacOS calls it a "bad random number generator".

Comment: `#include <random>` and then `std::srand(std::random_device{}());` :-)

Comment: But if you just need one value before you reseed, might as well just take the value from `std::random_device{}()` and use it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo    Easier to simply do `cout << std::random_device{}();`   and eliminate use of `rand()` entirely.  ;-)

Comment: These simple [examples on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3K6jqdEjW) show how to generate random integers and bools using `std::mt19937`. Function `random_integer` is templated, so it works with any integer type. Optional arguments for `min` and `max` allow you to specifiy the range of returned values. The random number engines and distributions are `thread_local`, so they don't conflict with each other in multithreaded environments.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you spend 30min of your life on watching the following: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `rand()` will return the same sequence of numbers for a given seed, which is why you see the change every second (you're seeding it with the time in seconds).

As for incrementing by 3 each time, `std::rand` is not guaranteed to produce sequences of any particular quality, and yours appears particularly not-that-great (not uncommon for `rand`). There are better quality generators in `<random>` (see docs [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)).

Comment: In particular most (all?) implementations of `rand` use a [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which is quite primitive.  The first few numbers you pull from it are highly correlated with the seed you started with.